# Is hosting my multiplayer HTML5 game on a free heroku dyno hurting my network performance?

Tags: html, networking, heroku, amazon-ec2, cloud

I've recently built a multiplayer game in HTML5 using the TCP-based WebSockets protocol for the networking. I already have taken steps in my code to minimize lag (using interpolation, minimizing the number of messages sent/message size), but I occasionally run into issues with lag and choppiness that I believe are happening due to a combination of packet loss and TCP's policy of in-order delivery.

To elaborate - my game sends out frequent websocket messages to players to update them on the position of the enemy players. If a packet gets dropped/delayed, my understanding is that it will prevent later packets from being received in a timely manner, which causes the enemy players to appear frozen in the same spot and then zoom to the correct location once the delayed packet is finally received.

I confess that my understanding of networking/bandwidth/congestion is quite weak. I've been wondering whether running my game on a single free heroku dyno, which is basically a VM on another virtual server (heroku dynos are on EC2 instances) could be exacerbating this problem. Do heroku dynos and multi-tenant servers in general tend to have worse network congestion due to noisy neighbors or other reasons?

Comment: Are you using nodejs? The "frozen and catch up" thing could also be a result of blocking node's event loop. It's hard to say without looking at code, but if you have only a few people online and it's consistently rocky, that might be it. Are all online users hitting the same functions on the server, or do they each have their own instance of functions? They should instantiate their own sessions when they connect so they won't block each others operations. Another [expensive] option is to not distribute, but scale the dynos so there are multiple instances of the otherwise blocked server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You don't get dedicated networking performance from Heroku instances. Some classes of EC2 instances in a VPC can have "Enhanced Networking" enabled which is supposed to help give you dedicated performance.

Ultimately, though the best thing to do before jumping to a new solution is benchmarking. Benchmark what level of throughput you can get from a Heroku dyno then try benchmarking an Amazon instance to see what kind of difference it makes.